# Visual Studio doesn't prompt me for a PIN when deploying to Hololens 2

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, hololens

I am trying to build a barebones Unity HL2 project to my HL2 device (followed [this guide](https://circuitstream.com/blog/hololens-2-setup-guide/) point by point). However, whenever I try to deploy through Visual Studio, the PIN box that usually appears to connect the HL2 with my laptop doesn't appear (I've made sure my HL2 isn't already paired with the laptop). I've tried again with a whole new project and it hasn't worked then too. I tried resetting my HL2 completely, but that didn't work either. I've tried out most if not all of the fixes that are proposed in other forums and stack overflow posts, including changing my debug target to x64, ensuring Developer mode is enabled on the Hololens, and installing USB Device connectivity for VS.

I'm including [the repository from github](https://github.com/evchin/holotest) if it helps: it's a small repo, as again, it's just a barebones HL2 demo.

The error I get when I deploy is below.

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       DEP6955: Timed out while attempting to connect to device '127.0.0.1' after '60' seconds.    hololens
```

Comment: For HoloLens2, please ensure the target of the build platform is "ARM64" and the target of Debugger to launch is "Device". Also, could you see the HoloLens device appear as a storage device in the file explorer once you plug in your HoloLens to the PC?  Wondering if your USB-C cable is faulty. And, could you try to unpair all devices in Setting from your HoloLens and restart your device to try again?

Comment: @Hernando-MSFT I have completed all of these, but still do not get the PIN screen unfortunately.

Comment: May it have to do with the fact that my HL2 used to be connected to my PC but I unpaired because it wasn't working and tried to repair - except now, the PIN window doesn't appear at all. @Hernando-MSFT

Comment: Could you open a support ticket through this link: http://aka.ms/hololenssupport so that we can provide you with a deeper diagnosis?